# What kind of applications can be created using jquery mobile

Tags: android, ios, design-patterns, mobile, jquery-mobile

i'm experienced with iOS application development and a little of Android development. But since most of my apps are asked to be platform independent(run on any mobile opertating system) i'm trying to find an alternate way to shorten development prosses. So, i decided to develope my app using JQueryMobile but i have some questions about it, for instance:

1. Can we create a kind of barcode reader on jquery mobile?
2. Are JQueryMobile apps just for web side or can be installed on device too?
3. Is it possible to use streams(socket-port programming) with JQueryMobile?
4. Will UI be auto completed related to the device if i use JQueryMobile..

I can ask a few questions too but i think these are enough to explain what i'm trying to ask. Please share your opinions, thanks in advance..
Note: As this question will expect for design patterns during application development for mobile and cross-platform applications, i will tag it with the tag **design-patterns** too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For creating platform independent applications, you can use **PhoneGap** .

Developing with PhoneGap gives you the freedom to create mobile applications for **iOS**, **Android**, **Blackberry**, **Windows Phone**, **Palm WebOS**, **Bada** and **Symbian** using the web code you know and love: HTML, CSS and Javascript.

See the details [here](http://phonegap.com)

Also you can create **barcode** reader or some other sensor-related things with it,also you can use Accelerometer/Maps/Camera And More with Phone gap. 
see the details

[Maps/Camera](http://maniacdev.com/2012/02/beginner-phonegap-tutorials-downloading-deployment-using-the-accelerometermapscamera-and-more/)

[Accelerometer](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_accelerometer_accelerometer.md.html)

[Magnetometer](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/16494794/iPhone%3a%20Magnetometer%20use)

[canvas-accelerometer-on-android](http://phonegap.com/2010/04/27/canvas-accelerometer-on-android/)

See more videos [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=14MhSnFJ3dc&feature=related)

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are better off creating an hybrid app using frameworks like PhoneGap than a pure web app. Limitations of pure web app approach is that you have limited access to device capabilities such as camera and also you cannot install it but has to be loaded from an web page. Phonegap packages your webapp into an installable format and also give you access to native APIs like camera from JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

I dont mean to be obvious, but JQueryMobile is a javascript framework for preseting information, arranging html elements to fit some (a lot I'd say) smartphone's browsers using html5.
I dont think you can entirly build an application which needs to control a barcode reader using only jquerymobile.

FYI:

[jquerymobile forum question about accessing the camera](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/mobile-phone-s-camera-access-with-jquery-mobile)

[apache cordova](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

**You can use phone gap witch can easily create phone apps for a lot of platforms, and its very easy and has got a lot of plugins, as u noted a barcode reader is one of them too, and the good thing is that you can develop an app the send it to there cloud build and it will be deployed to 6 platforms. so it will be cross platform with needing to RE-CODE for each OS.**