# Writing own phone gap plugin for iOS step by step

Tags: iphone, cordova, ios4, phonegap-plugins

It been a day scratching my head for this setup. I m feeling writing a plugin code is much easier than the setup.  I followed the below steps to to write a simple phone gap plugin for ios. But unfortunately, unable to locate where I missed. Kindly do printout the missing/confusing/erroneous part of the code.

**PhoneGap Setup:**

1) Closed Xcode. [ i have Xcode 4.3.3 ]
2) Downloaded latest phone gap. version 2.0 
3) in phonegap-phonegap-2dbbdab-1 directory,
    install Cordova-2.0.0.pkg

4) Ran the following code:

$ ./path/to/cordova-ios/bin/create /path/to/my_new_cordova_project com.example.cordova_project_name CordovaProjectName

*Followed*:
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/guide_command-line_index.md.html#Command-Line%20Usage

5)   Opened Xcode project.

6)   created HelloPlugin.js file under   www directory   that contains..

```
  var HelloPlugin = {

callNativeFunction: function (success, fail, resultType) {
    return Cordova.exec(success, fail, "com.tricedesigns.HelloPlugin", "nativeFunction", [resultType]);
}
};
```

7)  IN PLUGIN DIRECTORY

**HelloPlugin.h** contains:

```
#import "CDVPlugin.h"

@interface HelloPlugin : CDVPlugin {
      NSString* callbackID;
 }

 @property (nonatomic, copy) NSString* callbackID;

- (void) nativeFunction:(NSMutableArray*)arguments withDict:(NSMutableDictionary*)options;

@end
```

HelloPlugin.m contains:

```
#import "HelloPlugin.h"

@implementation HelloPlugin

 @synthesize callbackID;    


- (void) nativeFunction:(NSMutableArray*)arguments withDict:(NSMutableDictionary*)options {

    //get the callback id
    NSString *callbackId = [arguments pop];

    NSLog(@"Hello, this i s a native function called from PhoneGap/Cordova!");


    NSString *resultType = [arguments objectAtIndex:0]; 
    CDVPluginResult *result;

    if ( [resultType isEqualToString:@"success"] ) {
        result = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK messageAsString: @"Success :)"];
        [self writeJavascript:[result toSuccessCallbackString:callbackId]];
    }
    else {
        result = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_ERROR messageAsString: @"Error :("];
        [self writeJavascript:[result toErrorCallbackString:callbackId]];
    }
}

@end
```

**in Cordova.plist:**
  Have added 
       com.tricedesigns.HelloPlugin, HelloPlugin as key/value and type is string.

**in index.html:**

```
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="HelloPlugin.js"></script>

     <script type="text/javascript">
     function callNativePlugin( returnSuccess ) {
            alert("Inside callNativePlugin");
            HelloPlugin.callNativeFunction( nativePluginResultHandler, nativePluginErrorHandler, returnSuccess );
            alert("End of Hello PLugin");

        }

        function nativePluginResultHandler (result) {
            alert("SUCCESS: \r\n"+result );
        }

        function nativePluginErrorHandler (error) {
            alert("ERROR: \r\n"+error );
        }


</script>
```

Now when i click the button, the native function is not invoked. How to move forward?

Comment: my answer may helpful to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11723643/what-kind-of-applications-can-be-created-using-jquery-mobile/11724388#11724388

Answer (score 4):

I wrote a [tutorial](http://codrspace.com/vote539/writing-a-custom-camera-plugin-for-phonegap/) with step-by-step instructions on how to write a PhoneGap plugin for iOS.  It might be helpful for you.  Good luck!